# Displaying multiple objects one at a time in a dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I am completely stuck. I am trying to display objects individually in a pop-up dialog box, and I can't find any information as to how to do this. I can display them all at once, but that is not what I am trying to do.

```js
$.each(needs, function(i, v) {
  console.info(v);
  var brand = v.brand;
  console.info(brand);
  var model = v.model;
  var growerID = v.growerID;
  if (v.portalID === null) {
    var unmatched = {
      brand: v.brand,
      model: v.model,
      growerID: v.growerID
    }
    newmatch.push(unmatched);
    console.info(newmatch);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <form>
    <div class="fleft">
      <div>
        <img src="/app/public/css/images/logo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group brand ui-corner-all">
        <label for="owner">Brand</label>
        <div class="card-type ui-corner-all " id="brand"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group ui-corner-all">
        <label for="model">Model</label>
        <div class="model ui-corner-all " id="trxio_model"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group growerId">
        <label for="growerId">Grower ID</label>
        <div class="card-type ui-corner-all " id="growerId"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group vendor ui-corner-all ">
        <label for="owner">Default Vendor</label>
        <div class="card-type ui-corner-all " id="vendor"></div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">Update Product Info</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by individually? like one at a time?

Comment: Yes, I want to display one object in a dialog box, and then when a button is pressed, the next object is rendered to the dialog box. Basically, if the user does not want the first item, they can skip to the next

Answer (score 0):

Because you provided only a partial code that doesn't really work I've written a little example how to iterate over a collection of cars and how to render them into HTML container. Hopefully that will lead you to the solution:

```js
var cars = [
  {
    name: "VW",
    year: 1988,
  },
  {
    name: "Honda",
    year: 1999,
  },
  {
    name: "BMW",
    year: 2005,
  }
]

const container = document.querySelector('#container')

const toRender = cars.map(car => `<div class="car"><span class="name">${car.name}</span> <span class="year">${car.year}</span></div>`)

container.innerHTML = toRender.join('')
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 10;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.car {
  margin: 10px 0; 
}

.name {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #ff0000;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.year {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```